# Complete clueless how update model with foreign key in EF framework (migration)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i am on EF 6.1.3 lastest version

table relation is one to many

( both table has data but foreign key is not reflect after calling **update-database**)

here both model **rss_master** can have many **rss_master_publish**

```
[Table("dbo.rss_master")]
public class RssMasterModel
{
    [Key]
    public int userid { get; set; }
    public string prenom {get; set;}
    public string nom { get; set; }
    public string titre { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string phone_direct { get; set; }
    public string phone_client { get; set; }
    public string phone_other { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string fax { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RssMasterPublish> rssMasterPublish { get; set; }

}

[Table("dbo.rss_master_publish")]
public class RssMasterPublish
{
    [Key]
    public int id_publish { get; set; }
    public int userid { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string imgPath { get; set; }
    public DateTime datePublish { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("userid")]
    public virtual RssMasterModel rssMasterModel { get; set; }
}
```

**RssMasterPublish** is a new table that been add manually i want to launch console and call **update-database** and make change reflect on the database but nothing happen. I don't want to delete the data on that table if possible.

there is nothing much configure on DbContext here just setting

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

on **Configuration.cs** file the constructor only add

```
AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
```

i am kind confuse with all the migration think usually i just add new column and update the database but now i have relation with table that need to be change so if someone could help me out.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. You want a schema update to create the new table? You want to add records to a table based on a FK? You want to remove records from some table??

Comment: the FK is not reflect it i just want to add FK relation on the database but nothing happen

Comment: If you want good help you really need to be clearer in what you are trying to accomplish. So you have all of the data already populated in these 2 tables and now you want to reflect that in the relationship property `rssMasterModel` in your EF model and its not being populated? Or is the value in your new FK column userid null and now you want to populate it in your actual database?

Comment: both table is populate jsut want FK be reflect on calling update-database

Comment: You need to create a migration script. This needs to not only add a new column with a nullable value (thats the initial state afterall), it also needs to specify where the FK is coming from. Based on your last remark the `userid` property/column is new to the `RssMasterPublish` object/table so how will the existing data know what the correct value is. That is what you need to supply in the script. Honestly it might be easier writing this in transact sql instead of EF unless you do not have any type of access to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`update-database` will apply the latest migrations to the database. But it seems you have not yet created the migration for the foreign key in `RSSMasterPublish`.

You need to look at `add-migration`.

Comment: you mean when calling add-migration i add to setup foreign key inside the Up()  method for the specific migration file i call to make the reflect change in database?

Comment: i will tell you tomorrow not in my office i will give you feedback on it.